# Rails 5 API: Return multiple values for attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making an API that needs to return multiple values for a given attribute. I have a model named `User` and a user can like different types of fruits. A user could only like grapes, like grapes and apples, etc. I'm unsure how I can allow a user to like more than one fruit.

Here is what I have so far:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
   create_table :user do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.string :fruit
     t.timestamps
   end
 end
end
```

I'm unsure if I should bring fruits out into it's own model and make it `belongs_to :user` because I would only need the fruit's name. It would be weird to only have one attribute in my model. I was thinking of returning an array, but I don't know how, and I don't know if it's a proper API convention.

For example, if a user liked grapes and mangos, I would like a GET to /users/{:id}/fruits to return grapes and mangos. If a user did a POST to /user/{:id}/fruits I would like to add grapes and mangos.

So in conclusion, how should I structure my migration/model so I can get/post multiple values to my api?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Active Record Associations
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

like   **has_many**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that kind of structure, by declaring an additional table user_fruits which has joint primary key, user_id and fruit_id.

```
rails g model UserFruit user:references fruit:references
```

then make migration, which will create user_fruits in your database. 
Also add `has_and_belongs_to_many :fruits` to `User` model. And `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` to Fruit model.

```
UserFruit.create(:user_id => 1, :fruit_id =>1)

fruit_ids = [1,3,5,7]

fruit_ids.each do |f|
  UserFruit.create(:user_id=>2, :fruit_id => f)
end

user = User.find(2)
user.fruits.pluck(:id) # 1,3,5,7

fruit = Fruit.first
ids_of_users_likes_this_fruit = fruit.users.pluck(:id) # 1,2
```

[info 1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
[info 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

[Also have a look at to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33060595/4481312). The approach is same.